# How to get XBee MAC Address with Python?

Tags: python, linux, xbee

I found there are two Python modules `digicli` and `rci` for doing this, but the problem is when I want to import these modules, Python says:

```
No module named digicli
```

The same for "rci".

I've been trying to install these modules, but I can't find anything about it.

```
pip install digicli
```

does not work.

These are the modules:

- Digicli
  https://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Digicli
- Rci
  https://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Module:rci

Answer (score 0):

Those are modules specifically for Digi routers and gateways.  You're probably better off with this [XBee Python module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XBee).

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to use that module for getting the MAC address, any site could you provide?

Comment: Use ATSH and ATSL to query the high and low 32 bits of the serial number, which is the same as the MAC address.